# NP-intermediate approximation regimes for natural problems within the MAX-k-CSP family

Tags: approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, approximation, csp, np-intermediate

I would like to know whether there are any examples of natural problems within the MAX-$k$-CSP family for which (under standard/reasonable conjectures) we believe the following:

- There is a value $\epsilon_1$ such that approximation within a factor of $\epsilon_1$ is possible in polynomial time.
- There is a value $\epsilon_2$ such that approximation within a factor of $\epsilon_2$ is NP-hard.
- There is some value $\epsilon$ between $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ such that approximation within a factor of $\epsilon$ are neither in polynomial time nor NP-Hard.

(There is a general question about NP-intermediate problems [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc/237#237), but it is much more general in its problem domain, as well as oriented towards the exact-answer setting)

Answer (score 2):

The sidebar algorithm has done its work, and linked to [this similar question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/hard-gaps-in-maximum-constraint-satisfaction-problems?rq=1). The accepted answer there explains that under the Unique Games Conjecture, no such regimes exist.